# Add custom font to website

Tags: css, fonts

I downloaded a font from Google Fonts - Arimo.
I created a master page and a stylesheet and I wrote this:

```
@font-face{
    font-family:"Arimo";
    src: url('../Fonts/Arimo/Arimo-Regular.ttf'),format('truetype');
}
body, html{
    font-family:Arimo; 
}
```

when i created an .aspx page i linked the master page but the font is not recognized. however when i use this google link:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo" rel="stylesheet" />
```

it is work. Can someone explain me why is the first methode dont work and how can i fix it?

Comment: `body { font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif;}` should fix it

Comment: @sandip_rb why do you think so ?

Comment: @sandip_rb it recognize only the sans-serif, in other pages it doesnt even show to Arimo in font-family

Comment: there is no comma between `url` and `format`.

Comment: It Works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to upload the downloaded font on your server. You must upload/add the font in Fonts/Arimo/ folder then the font must work on your webpage.

Comment: i have the downloaded font in my web files

Comment: What you mean? I downloaded it from Goggle Fonts, Unzip it and i created new folder called Fonts, in it another folder called Arimo and in it i did 'Add existing Item' and i Added the fonts, all with the .ttf end

Comment: If your CSS file and fonts folder are in same directory then you can replace your src: code with the following code:

src: url('fonts/Arimo/Arimo-Regular.ttf');

and if your CSS file is in other directory then replace your src code with src: url(‘../fonts/Arimo/Arimo-Regular.ttf');

I tried it here and it is working fine.